# How do I teleport a zombie to me every time it gets too far by using a command block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to teleport a zombie to me if it gets too far from me but the command block only does it if the zombie is far from itself.

The command I tried is `/execute as @p run tp @e[type=zombie,distance=5..] @p`

Answer (score 1):

`as` executes a command as your person, (so for example `kill @s` would kill you and not the command block), you want `at`, which executes at your position.